# How to: implement a basic php paging with mysql, ajax AND linq

Tags: php, mysql, linq, paging

Am trying to implement a simple mysql data paging using php, ajax and (the real kicker) linq. There is a linq implementation for php, called phplinq

I have been able to implement the paging without the linq part, and the relevant code is this: (split into several files)

1. pagination.php, where it all starts.

   Pagination with Jquery, Ajax, PHP

   > ```
   >      <script type="text/javascript"
   > ```
   >
   > src="js/jquery1_5_2_min.js">
2. load_data.php, the file where the data is all pulled

   ```
       $query_pag_data = "SELECT id as msg_id,name as message from student LIMIT $start, $per_page";
       $result_pag_data = mysql_query($query_pag_data) or die('MySql Error' . mysql_error());
       $msg = "";
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_data)) {
           $htmlmsg=htmlentities($row['message']);
           $msg .= "<li><b>" . $row['msg_id'] . "</b> " . $htmlmsg . "</li>";
       }
       $msg = "<div class='data'><ul>" . $msg . "</ul></div>"; // Content for Data

       /* --------------------------------------------- */
       $query_pag_num = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM student";
       $result_pag_num = mysql_query($query_pag_num);
       $row = mysql_fetch_array($result_pag_num);
       $count = $row['count'];
       $no_of_paginations = ceil($count / $per_page);

       /* ---------------Calculating the starting and endign values for the loop----------------------------------- */
       if ($cur_page >= 7) {
           $start_loop = $cur_page - 3;
           if ($no_of_paginations > $cur_page + 3)
               $end_loop = $cur_page + 3;
           else if ($cur_page <= $no_of_paginations && $cur_page > $no_of_paginations - 6) {
               $start_loop = $no_of_paginations - 6;
               $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
           } else {
               $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
           }
       } else {
           $start_loop = 1;
           if ($no_of_paginations > 7)
               $end_loop = 7;
           else
               $end_loop = $no_of_paginations;
       }
       /* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
       $msg .= "<div class='pagination'><ul>";

       // FOR ENABLING THE FIRST BUTTON
       if ($first_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
           $msg .= "<li p='1' class='active'>First</li>";
       } else if ($first_btn) {
           $msg .= "<li p='1' class='inactive'>First</li>";
       }

       // FOR ENABLING THE PREVIOUS BUTTON
       if ($previous_btn && $cur_page > 1) {
           $pre = $cur_page - 1;
           $msg .= "<li p='$pre' class='active'>Previous</li>";
       } else if ($previous_btn) {
           $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Previous</li>";
       }
       for ($i = $start_loop; $i <= $end_loop; $i++) {

           if ($cur_page == $i)
               $msg .= "<li p='$i' style='color:#fff;background-color:#006699;' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
           else
               $msg .= "<li p='$i' class='active'>{$i}</li>";
       }

       // TO ENABLE THE NEXT BUTTON
       if ($next_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
           $nex = $cur_page + 1;
           $msg .= "<li p='$nex' class='active'>Next</li>";
       } else if ($next_btn) {
           $msg .= "<li class='inactive'>Next</li>";
       }

       // TO ENABLE THE END BUTTON
       if ($last_btn && $cur_page < $no_of_paginations) {
           $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='active'>Last</li>";
       } else if ($last_btn) {
           $msg .= "<li p='$no_of_paginations' class='inactive'>Last</li>";
       }
       $goto = "<input type='text' class='goto' size='1' style='margin-top:-1px;margin-left:60px;'/><input type='button' id='go_btn' class='go_button' value='Go'/>";
       $total_string = "<span class='total' a='$no_of_paginations'>Page <b>" . $cur_page . "</b> of <b>$no_of_paginations</b></span>";
       $msg = $msg . "</ul>" . $goto . $total_string . "</div>";  // Content for pagination
       echo $msg;
   }
   ```
3. dbconnect.php, containing login stuff
4. paginator.js, the file with javascript functions.

   $(document).ready(function(){
       function loading_show(){
           $('#loading').html("").fadeIn('fast');
       }
       function loading_hide(){
           $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
       }
       function loadData(page){
           loading_show();
           $.ajax
           ({
               type: "POST",
               url: "load_data.php",
               data: "page="+page,
               success: function(msg)
               {
                   $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                   {
                       loading_hide();
                       $("#container").html(msg);
                   });
               }
           });
       }
       loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
       $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
           var page = $(this).attr('p');
           loadData(page);

   ```
   });           
   $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
       var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
       var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
       if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
           loadData(page);
       }
       else{
           alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
           $('.goto').val("").focus();
           return false;            
       }
   });
   ```

   });

And finally, table.css, the file with some basic styling.

```
body{
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
#loading{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
    margin-top:200px;
}
#container .pagination ul li.inactive,
#container .pagination ul li.inactive:hover{
    background-color:#ededed;
    color:#bababa;
    border:1px solid #bababa;
    cursor: default;
}
#container .data ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: verdana;
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
}

#container .pagination{
    width: 800px;
    height: 25px;
}
#container .pagination ul li{
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #006699;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 6px;
    margin: 0 3px 0 3px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #006699;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#container .pagination ul li:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #006699;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.go_button
{
background-color:#f2f2f2;border:1px solid #006699;color:#cc0000;padding:2px 6px 2px 6px;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;margin-top:-1px;
}
.total
{
float:right;font-family:arial;color:#999;
}
```

if youre going to replicate this, there is a css folder and a js folder and i have downloaded the jquery 1.5.2 from google. you can replace the line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1_5_2_min.js"></script>
```

in pagination.php with

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, the table being used is

```
CREATE TABLE student    (
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(150)
);
my
```

objective here is get rid of all direct mysql query calls inside the files with whatever i can put there using linq. I have used linq extensively with .NET 4.0, so basically what am trying to do here is abstracting the data access layer, as if i were using .NET objects to interface with data instead of pure mysql query calls.

Does this make sense? my end goal is being able to replace all mysql query calls with phplinq and completely isolate the data access code.(If linq is an overkill or somehow inadequate, ill drop it)  I dont want to go with any ORM here because am going to heavily customize the grid (In this example there is just a list) and the future Data Access Layer

Am not that proficient   with php, so please dont direct me to extensive reading. something i could pick up and play with would be much better

Comment: What's your actual question? What problem are you facing?

Comment: am trying to put the paginator.php code but i cant make it show html code

Comment: how can replace the mysql direct calls with linq calls. thats the actual question, or a variant of it, can this pagination scheme work if i fed it arrays or objects instead of direct mysql query calls?

Comment: you see, my end goal is to completely encapsulate all data access in one place. like i said, i wont be using any orm for this.. the problem is that it seems to me that all these (and ive tried several) pagination tutorials rely heavily on the mysql builtin LIMIT feature

Comment: PHPLinq is itself just a DAL wrapper around the standard PHP mysql/mysqli/PDO extensions. It doesn't have any deeper integration than that, so unless you want to fetch all records from the database first, you'll have to use `LIMIT`.

Comment: so, in your view, there is no way i can implement paging without issuing direct mysql calls inside that paging code?

Comment: I have no idea how you'd do the same thing in Linq, but whatever tools or syntax PHPLinq gives you, it'll have to generate a `LIMIT` clause somehow in the end, if you're talking to a MySQL database. I imagine there's some way to generate that in PHPLinq syntax, but it's the same thing in the end.

Comment: that is not a problem. my problem is that i dont want to have mysql_query calls all over the place. i just want them in one place. thing is, these tutorials ive been seeing use the LIMIT feature to help them with the paging,meaning id have to query data in more than one place, which i dont want. generally what am thinking about is feeding the data to the paginate function. BUT, as the paginate function calls LIMIT inside it... do you see my problem?

Comment: I really have no real idea what you're talking about. It'd help if you could summarize your problem better. Just a simple code snippet of what you have, want you want and what the problem in doing it is. The pages and pages of code you posted seem to have little to do with your actual question.

Comment: maybe i didnt explain it properly. i will create another question and direct you to it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369904/how-to-implement-php-mysql-data-pagination-using-data-providers

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you're having a problem with fetching records from database.. I have worked in php paging alot and trust me php works better with mySQL queries than LINQ.. You can check out a blog post on LINQ Paging [here](http://wahabkotwal.blogspot.com/2011/06/aspnet-ajax-simple-paging-system-using.html) . Its using ASP.net but im pretty sure you can get atleast and idea to do your work.. Whenever I go for paging with LINQ i usually use this query

`(from ac in dc.students where StudentIDs.Contains(ac.Ids) select ac).Skip((PageNumber - 1) * NumberOfRecordsInPage).Take(NumberOfRecordsInPage)`

Hope it helps :)